# Game theory:- value of a game?

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I haven't found any suitable explanation or even definition for this concept. ***What is the value of game in game theory?*** Can anybody explain it to me with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a game is the expected value to a given player.  For example, a game where you flip a coin and win $2$ for heads and lose $1$ for tails has a value to you of $\frac 12\cdot 2 + \frac 12 \cdot (-1)=\frac 12$.  If you have to pay $\frac 12$ to play the game you will break even in the long run.

Comment: What do you mean by `break even in the long run`? Because my gain and payment cancel out and I have no profit?
Also have you seen the comment of Briang Tung above? I feel both of you are right and exactly these two cases in my mind made me confused. Can you shed some light on Brian's comment? And your last comment?

Comment: On average, each time you play you have a profit of $\frac 12$.  If you have to pay $\frac 12$ to play, your expectation becomes $0$.  On average, then you do not gain or lose.  Brian Tung is saying the same thing but focusing on cases where the players have options of how to play.  The simple game above does not have any options, you just play.

Comment: .: SO now if I have a game where I have options to play (2 player Normal form game) with a specific strategy, should we always consider value at certain equilibrium or the generalized expected pay off in case both of the players are following a mixed strategy? SImply put there might be many values in different ways, which one should we consider if somebody says "consider the value of a game"

Comment: As Brian Tung says, you would consider the equilibrium because paying any more than that can leave you with a loss if the other player plays rationally.

Comment: .: you mean playing anything less than those equilibrium (maybe something not NE) would leave me losing somehting compared to what I would get if I played the equilibrium? I will upvote you because it makes sense.

Comment: @mathuser001 Ultimately, it comes down to the value of each possible outcome, and the probability of achieving each of those outcomes. The probability of achieving certain outcomes can change depending on different players' strategies, so in the absence of that knowledge, we may assume a uniform distribution over strategies or random moves. If I know a Rock-Paper-Scissors opponent always throws rock, I can win with probability 1, but without knowing their strategy, I can only expect to win 1/3 of the time.

Comment: Paying less than the equilibrium is in your favor.  Paying more is not.  In my example, if you pay less than $\frac 12$ you have a long term profit.

Comment: @RossMillikan Actually I think that NE is a point from which if anybody moves he/she would get less payoff. So NE is the maximum payoff case and we shouldnt deviate from it, (General sense I am saying - dont consider those equilibrium refinements)

Comment: That is correct.  You can guarantee yourself the NE against any opposing strategy.  In your next to last comment you talked about paying less than NE, but I think you meant you should not pay more than that.  The game is paying you at least NE, so if you pay no more than that you are OK.

Answer (score 0):

One definition of the "value of a game" is as the nim-value or "nimber" of a game. The Sprague-Grundy Theorem says that all games (satisfying a few standard assumptions true of most combinatorial games) are equivalent to a single nimheap, i.e. they behave the same way under game addition. The number of stones in the nimheap is the "nimber," which is perhaps what the value of a game means.

More reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nim-Value.html

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague–Grundy_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

As in general game theory, the Value of game is to be the minimax of the payoff. Symbolically,
$$V(x)=\min_{\phi(x)}\max_{\psi(x)}(\text{ payoff }).$$

From [Rufus Isaacs - Differential Games_ A Mathematical Theory with Applications to Warfare and Pursuit, Control and Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486406822)